# Convert XML to array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, arraylist

I'm Trying to convert this xml to array saving the attributes names.
Because I need to send this parameters to a Client using Wcf, and the client needs to display that information

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <Cameras>
   <Camera Name="Camera1" Url="Camera1" Width="600" Height="800" />
   <Camera Name="Camera2" Url="Camera2" Width="600" Height="800" />
</Cameras>
</Configuration>
```

I'm using C#

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways,

**Using Linq to XML**

You can get array of `Name` attributes by using linq to xml

```
string testData = @"<Configuration>
                                <Cameras>
                                    <Camera Name =""Camera1"" Url = ""Camera1"" Width = ""600"" Height = ""800"" />       
                                    <Camera Name = ""Camera2"" Url = ""Camera2"" Width = ""600"" Height = ""800"" />
                                </Cameras>
                            </Configuration>";

            XDocument xdc = XDocument.Parse(testData);
            var arrNames = xdc.Root
                .Descendants("Camera")
                .Select(e => e.Attribute("Name")).ToArray();
```

**Using XML serialization**

Create class structure of your xml, deserialize xml to object and you can get list of all your required properties

xml

```
<Configuration>
  <Cameras>
   <Camera Name="Camera1" Url="Camera1" Width="600" Height="800" />
   <Camera Name="Camera2" Url="Camera2" Width="600" Height="800" />
</Cameras>
</Configuration>
```

C# Classes

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Camera")]
    public class Camera {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Width")]
        public string Width { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Height")]
        public string Height { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Cameras")]
    public class Cameras {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Camera")]
        public List<Camera> Camera { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Configuration")]
    public class Configuration {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Cameras")]
        public Cameras Cameras { get; set; }
    }

}
```

To deserialize xml use below code

```
string testData = @"<Configuration>
                            <Cameras>
                                <Camera Name =""Camera1"" Url = ""Camera1"" Width = ""600"" Height = ""800"" />       
                                <Camera Name = ""Camera2"" Url = ""Camera2"" Width = ""600"" Height = ""800"" />
                            </Cameras>
                        </Configuration>";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
        // testData is your xml string
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(testData))
        {
            Configuration result = (Configuration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

Comment: Actually a better way to implement but OP asked for Array so provided the solution like that

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee OP will make decision how he will implement and whats fit with his solution

Comment: How can I flatten that so I get 
<code>
Configuration{ 
     Camera [] cameras;
}
</code>
So I don't need an surrounding "Cameras" class?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arr = XDocument.Load(@"FileNamewithPath.xml").Descendants("NodeName")
                    .Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

should work for you

you can also use like this `.Select(x => (int) x)` if names are not their

Comment: In your case it will be Camera